# Stop oracle client connection on windows 10

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, oracle, odbc

I'm testing a vb.net application that connect with oracle database on remote server and run some SQL queries. I want to show a warning message if the connection to the oracle DB is lost/ or in case o connection time out.

To test this i need to stop or deactivate the connection to the oracle databse on windows 10. I have oracle 11 client installed on my PC, i don't know how to Stop or break the connection to oracle DB outside my application on windows 10. I also have opened wondows services, and did not find oracle service. could you please support to solve this problem.

Comment: You don't know how to pull out a network cable?

Comment: of course in know this. I have also a code to chekc the network connection, but i need to check if the DB is not responding (e.g connection time out )

Comment: Or ask your DBA to kill the session

Answer (score 0):

Here are two example on how you can test that. I'm sure there are multiple other ways :

- Try to connect to a wrong database host/port
- Try to correctly connect to database and in your code add something to disconnect from the database and continue the execution to see how your code reacts